# PHP developer thinking of Java

Tags: c#, java, php

I'm a PHP developer trying to learn a new language which has better security and performance. I heard that facebook is built on C# and PHP front end. I was thinking of learning Java and use it backend, business logics and use PHP for front-end. Is this a great combination for big websites/webapps or not?

Answer (score 3):

It is possiple, but each of these languages have it's own stack of technologies. If you intended to use Java, i'd recommend you to use JSP instead of PHP (same with ASP for C#). It allows you to use advanced possibilities, provided by these languages.

Comment: What do you think of using JSF instead of JSP?

Comment: JSF is a web framework, that uses JSP as a display tool, so you can't compare them. But still, if you intended to use pure Java, there are many web frameworks to ease your life: JSF, GWT, Struts, Spring MVC, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not use C#,  instead,  it uses [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) to compile the php code into c++.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Java and PHP are the best gears for web developers. So try to learn java instead of C#. Also Java has cross-platform support

Comment: What does mean "Yes. You are wrong"?))) And I wrote "In my opinion" as you see